# Instagram API Follower List Export

Tags: csv, instagram-api

Does anybody know of a simple way to use the Instagram API to export a list of a user's followers? I'm looking to be able to take a list of people that follow me, and a list of people that follow another user, then find all of the common followers, and finally pick a certain number of random usernames from the common followers. I know it sounds a bit complex, but mostly I just need a way to get the list of followers, and I should be able to figure out the rest. A CSV File would probably do what I need if possible. So does anyone know how to do this, or have a tutorial you could direct me to? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do this. But you can no longer do it using the Instagram API. The Instagram API is no longer accepting new applications and it is being shut down in stages starting on the 31st of July 2018:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

However, there is another way to obtain the data. You can export the followers of any Instagram account into a CSV file using this website:

[www.magimetrics.com](https://www.magimetrics.com)

It is very easy to use Magi Metrics. Sign up for an account, search for the username of the Instagram account you want to export and choose the option 'Export followers'. Magi Metrics will do all the work and will email you the CSV file once it's done. It's free to use for exports less than 100 rows, and you can pay to upgrade to do more.

Using Magi Metrics you can export a list of all the people that follow you, and all the people who follow another user. You can then take these two CSV files and copy them into Microsoft Excel.

In the first column you will find the Instagram numerical ID, which is unique to each user. If you apply the COUNTIF formula to this column, you can identify the Instagram users who are in both lists:

http://spreadsheetpro.net/comparing-two-columns-unique-values/

Finally, to choose a random subset from the list of Instagram users, you can use this method:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4487-excel-generate-random-number-from-list.html

Using these steps you can achieve what you want: a random subset from the list of Instagram accounts who both follow your account and another user!

I appreciate this question dates from 2016, so your need has probably long gone. But if anyone else on the Internet faces the same problem, I've posted this answer to help them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're luck.I found a tool easily no longer do it using the Instagram API.
you can have a try. [InsExport](https://savemydayapp.com/export-instagram-followers-to-spreadsheet/)

How does it work?

1 Enter an Instagram username

2 Select the export type(follwer or following)

3 Click the Export button

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insexport-get-instagram-f/okmokimdgjhndamggnkdojhbofdmepno?hl=zh-CN&authuser=0

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Programatically, you can easily request a list of up to 100 of your own followers. With one token, that's the max per request.

Here's the full documentation from Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Automated services will get a list of all your followers by requesting them 100 at a time using multiple tokens, getting around that 5,000 request limit (https://www.crowdbabble.com/download-all-instagram-followers/).